# Some questions about java coding style

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have been studying java for like 2 months and I'm familiar with classes, inheritance and also a little bit about swing.
I have seen some experts' coding style and I do fell a little bit unfamiliar with it.
For example:
1)

```
import java.util.Calendar;

    class testIni2{
      public static void main(String args[]){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);

        System.out.println("Today's date is" + month + " " + day );
      }
    }
```

From my previous knowledge, if you want to create an instace of a class, most of the style I have seen is like below:

```
Calendar cal = new Calendar();
```

followed by calling the methods, in this case I think its like this:

```
cal.getInstance();
```

I understand the rest of it. Does it mean that I can directly call the method when I am creating the instance of the class? Lets say if I have a dog class and inside it has a method called 'bark', I can do something like this:

```
Dog cutie = Dog.bark();      // Like this??
```

2) http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/firstprograms/

I read a tutorial about swing from this site, and another question about its coding style.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SimpleEx extends JFrame {

    public SimpleEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setTitle("Simple example");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SimpleEx ex = new SimpleEx();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Just as same as my previous question but this time he created another method for initializing and call it inside the constructor which I find it a little bit confusing. I have also seen Derek Bananas youtube tutorial and he wrote the code like this:

```
this.setTitle...     
this.setSize...
```

Which means I also can use 'this.' inside the initUI method too??

PS: If you feel that my questions are due to my lack of study, could you please tell me some keywords that I can google it? Sorry if my English is bad. Thank you.

Comment: [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) doesn't have a public constructor. And yes, you can use `this.` in any instance method.

Comment: What you're looking for is called "static method".

Comment: For your question about `Dog cutie = Dog.bark();` the short answer is NO, you can't unless the method bark() IS static AND also return a instance of Dog class.

Answer (score 5):

what youre seeing is the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). the class author (whoever wrote Calendar) decided that, for whatever reason, they dont want the class' user (you, in this case) to create a Calendar directly.

usually this is because:

1. there are various kinds of calendars, and which one you get is basically none of your business :-)
2. maybe building a new Calendar is a lot of work and the library only has one, so everyone who calls the factory method gets the same one.
3. building a Calendar is too complicated for most mere mortals.

as for your Dog line:

```
Dog cutie = Dog.bark();
```

bark() is a bad name for a method that returns a dog - very unintuitive.
lets say, for example that your Dog class is very complicated - it has age, sex, breed, color, and size. 
and every dog must have all those specified.
you could make it easier for developers to create dogs by either implementing a DogFactory:

```
public class DogFactory {
   public static Dog newDog() {
      return new Dog(1, Sex.MALE, Breed.PUDLE, brown, 40);
   }
}
```

a related design pattern would be [the builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), where code using a builder could look like this:

```
Dog lassie = new DogBuilder().called("lassie").ofBreed(Breed.COLLIE).ofHeight(60).build();
```

the internal implementation of a builder is slightly more complicated than a factory

Comment: Would be better if you add a note about his line `Dog cutie = Dog.bark();` :)

Comment: Thanks radai. Does the second one also the factory patter? I think its all about design pattern right?

Comment: @nicklowkc - i dont understand exactly what you mean by "the second one". could you elaborate please?